# Solving matrices

Tags: matrices

Lately I sought for some challenge for my logical part of brain. In mathematics. I Googled a website and wanted to learn something new, so I met matrixes, I remember it from Microsoft Office, so I wanted to give it a shot.

But as I told, this was something new, I wasn't entirely sure how to solve it, I keep looking 'n then I switched to Google, then I saw that "my exercise" doesn't look like all others in tutorials. I think I get how matrices work due to these Oh Great! tutorials:

YouTube.com/watch?v=oNKI8Fut1E4 (sorry for such strange link, input doesn't allow more than 2 links)

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

But my equation consists only of 2 rows and columns:

http://math.ly/arithmetic/matrices/qtfbpbnsf/

Do I put split in center, or I need to put $11x + 1y$ or is $11x = 1$, ($x=11^{-1}$?) I don't really know. If you're about to jump on me yelling that if I don't know how to solve it, I shouldn't approach, it won't affect the way I learn, it was always that way, fastest way, greatest quality way etc. .

Comment: I don't think I entirely understand your question - but I will try to say something useful. The question you link to asks you to calculate the determinant of the matrix, which you can do without thinking at all about a linear system that the matrix might represent.

Comment: As a side note, I like your name OP.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you solving questions on math.ly? Then, as Matt says, the question you have linked to is about determinants, and is not really related to solving equations. You should read up on determinants first.

Comment: @DanZimm It's unrelated. M. Vinay, strict and fast > I need help with answering question, in posted link.

Answer (score 3):

"Your equation" is asking you to calculate the determinant of the matrix. From your question I suspect that you don't know what the determinant is. The best way for you would be if you started to study math in a more structured way. If you are interested in matrices you can start to learn linear algebra, there are tons of resources available for that.

Like this one from MIT: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/

Or you could start with a resource like Khan academy that is a bit less rigorous. https://www.khanacademy.org